# how to make a carousel bigger only on mobile screens?

Tags: carousel, bootstrap-4

I'd like to make a bigger carousel on mobile devices. Is there any way to accomplish this?
As you look at my code, you'll see that carousel on mobile screen is tiny:
https://codepen.io/Codewife_101/pen/XeJaLR

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand Name</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav2"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav2">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Products</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
  </nav>


<!--Showcase-->
<section id="showcase">
  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://lorempixel.com/1600/450" alt="First slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://lorempixel.com/1600/450" alt="Second slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://lorempixel.com/1600/450" alt="Third slide">
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true">
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
</section>
```

The idea is to upload three different pictures 1, 2, 3. I used lorempixels just for showing the desired size, but in a real life I want to upload 3 different pictures. The solution given by @cwanjt works well with some minor adjustments, but as an end-result, I need something different. I'm thinking about "hidden" classes in Bootstrap 4. Any thoughts?
My CSS:

`.carousel-inner > .item > img {
      min-width: 100%;
      width: 100%;
}`

Comment: It looks different here than in CodePen. I couldn't add js files here.

Comment: Your carousel appears to occupy the full width at both desktop and mobile screen widths.

Comment: I didn't upload CSS, but I've just changed it.

Comment: @Kate, what do you mean by bigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll take a guess at what you're trying to accomplish and hopefully I'm in the ballpark. Instead of having two different carousels, what you can do is use some good old CSS `media` queries to change the URL for the `img` elements.

Remove the `src` attributes from the `img` elements, and create a class that implements the `content` property with `url(path/to/image/file)` value.

```
.change-img {
      content: url(http://lorempixel.com/1600/750);
    }
```

Now create a media query that will change the value of the URL when the viewport reaches a specified size.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    .change-img {
      content: url(http://lorempixel.com/1600/1550);
    }
}
```

Add the class to your `img` element.

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block w-100 change-img" alt="First slide">
      </div>
      ...
```

I forked your [codepen](https://codepen.io/cowanjt/pen/VMYMrR?editors=1100) and implemented this code, so you can see it working. Just resize the browser to 700px and you'll see the first image in the carousel will have a larger height.

Comment: The thing is I want to make a carousel bigger on mobile devices. I wasn't precise; by that, I mean mostly IPhones. I looked at the CodePan and it doesn't work for me. I'll try to use it with a real-life example and  I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: It works on CodePan. I added "change-img"  to all <img class="d-block w-100">. Great solution!

Comment: I applied this code in a real-life scenario, and it works, but it's not very modular. I need to use three different images every time. I used lorempixel just for stackoverflow. I guess I should have mentioned this earlier in my question. I'm thinking about "hidden" classes, or maybe "invisible". I need to educate myself what is more suitable in this particular case. Do you have any other solutions?

Comment: Since you're using bootstrap 4, you could use the `hidden-*-up` and hidden-*-down` classes where the * represents a bootstrap breakpoint (`sm`, `md`, `lg`). A more programmatic way would be to use SASS and put the url for your images into variables and loop through them, while still using the method I described above. I've updated my [codepen](https://codepen.io/cowanjt/pen/VMYMrR?editors=1100), so you can see what that would look like.